# as3 remove opaque background on mouseup

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Howzit I have a bitmap on a button. On mousedown I want to give the button an opaque background and on release to return it to its transparent state.

I tried the following

```
      function exitmsdwn(event:MouseEvent):void {

        favouriteblendsexitButton.opaqueBackground = 0xFF0000;
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, completeRect);

    }

    function completeRect(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, completeRect);
        favouriteblendsexitButton.opaqueBackground = false;
    }
```

However after it goes false it has a black background and not a transparent one.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Which kind of buttons are you using ? and what's `opaqueBackground` and how do you use it ?

Comment: the buttons are sprites.  Not sure how to answer opaqueBackground it is a flash command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you are speaking about [`DisplayObject.opaqueBackground`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#opaqueBackground) which you can just set it to `null` to get a transparent background :

```
favouriteblendsexitButton.opaqueBackground = null;
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Also if you don't mind if I can ask you another question, i see the mousedown doesnt trigger on touchescreen when you hold your finger down only if you swipe your finger?  How do i make it work on touchscreen if you just hold your finger down?

Thanks

Comment: @AdamKatz You can use a [`TouchEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html) instead. More details [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-6ffb37601221e58cc29-8000.html) ...